# Differentiate between two JSON responses

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm having issues seperating how to handle two JSOn responses.  IF there is only one element returned, it gives a different response than two:

Here is one result:

```
{
    "voteMap": {
        "SID": "2727",
        "CNT": "1",
        "VTD": "N"
    }
}
```

And two:

```
{
    "voteMap": [
        {
            "SID": "2814",
            "CNT": "1",
            "VTD": "N"
        },
        {
            "SID": "2815",
            "CNT": "1",
            "VTD": "N"
        }
    ]
}
```

I go from having one array to having an array of dictionaries.  Here is how I am handling it:

```
responseArr = jsonArray[@"voteMap"];

  if([jsonArray count] == 1){
       Song* song = [self findSong:[responseArr valueForKey:@"SID"]];
       song.votes =[responseArr valueForKey:@"CNT"];
       song.status = [responseArr valueForKey:@"VTD"];
        }           
   else{
         for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArr) {
            Song *song = [self findSong:[dict valueForKey:@"SID"]];
            song.votes =[dict valueForKey:@"CNT"];
            song.status = [dict valueForKey:@"VTD"];
            }
        }
```

Sorry about the bad formatting.  What is happening is the `[jsonArray count] == 1` is always happening...presumable because it always returns `voteMap`

Comment: Yes, use isKindOfClass.

Comment: And if the kind of class is a dictionary, wrap the dictionary in an array and let it simply fall through to the array logic.  That way you don't have to write anything twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray* responseArr = [response objectForKey:@"voteMap"];
if ([responseArr isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   responseArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:responseArr];
}
for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArr) {
    Song *song = [self findSong:[dict valueForKey:@"SID"]];
    song.votes =[dict valueForKey:@"CNT"];
    song.status = [dict valueForKey:@"VTD"];
}
```

(I've used this model several times.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking the type with something like this:

```
id object = [response objectForKey:@"voteMap"];
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // process multible objects
} else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // process individual object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
responseArr = jsonArray[@"voteMap"];
    if ([responseArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArr) {
            Song *song = [self findSong:[dict valueForKey:@"SID"]];
            song.votes =[dict valueForKey:@"CNT"];
            song.status = [dict valueForKey:@"VTD"];
            }
    }
    if ([responseArr isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
Song* song = [self findSong:[responseArr valueForKey:@"SID"]];
       song.votes =[responseArr valueForKey:@"CNT"];
       song.status = [responseArr valueForKey:@"VTD"];
        }  

    }
```

i think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Dope! I was looking for a function like this.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isKindOfClass` method to determinate it is a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

try following code. and check the json is array or dictionary

```
id jsonArray;
if([jsonArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

    Song* song = [self findSong:[responseArr valueForKey:@"SID"]];
    song.votes =[responseArr valueForKey:@"CNT"];
    song.status = [responseArr valueForKey:@"VTD"];
}
else{
    for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArr) {
        Song *song = [self findSong:[dict valueForKey:@"SID"]];
        song.votes =[dict valueForKey:@"CNT"];
        song.status = [dict valueForKey:@"VTD"];
    }
}
```